# Node.js Paypal how to send other data alongside the trigger

Tags: node.js, express, paypal

I am attempting to send data alongside the code for paypal to the node.js client, but I am not sure where to send that data alongside it.

Here is the client side paypal code:

```
paypal.Buttons({
        // Order is created on the server and the order id is returned
        createOrder: (data, actions) => {
         
          return fetch("/api/orders", {
            method: "post",
            // use the "body" param to optionally pass additional order information
            // like product ids or amount
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((order) => order.id);
        },
        // Finalize the transaction on the server after payer approval
        onApprove: (data, actions) => {
          return fetch(`/api/orders/${data.orderID}/capture`, {
            method: "post",
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((orderData) => {
            // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
            const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
            alert(`Transaction ${transaction.status}: ${transaction.id}\n\nSee console for all available details`);
            // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
            // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
            // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
          });
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Here is the server side paypal code:

```
app.post("/api/orders", async (req, res) => {
  const order = await createOrder();
  res.json(order);
});

// capture payment & store order information or fullfill order
app.post("/api/orders/:orderID/capture", async (req, res) => {
  
  const { orderID } = req.params;
  const captureData = await capturePayment(orderID);
  // TODO: store payment information such as the transaction ID
  res.json(captureData);
});

//////////////////////
// PayPal API helpers
//////////////////////

// use the orders api to create an order
async function createOrder() {
  const accessToken = await generateAccessToken();
  const url = `${base}/v2/checkout/orders`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      intent: "CAPTURE",
      purchase_units: [
        {
          amount: {
            currency_code: "USD",
            value: "100.00",
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

// use the orders api to capture payment for an order
async function capturePayment(orderId) {
  const accessToken = await generateAccessToken();
  const url = `${base}/v2/checkout/orders/${orderId}/capture`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });
  const data = await response.json(); 
  return data;
}
```

The issue is there is no req.body.stuff anywhere.
The goal I am trying to achieve, is is when the payment is made, I want to send the data of like the string "potato", Before the actual payment goes through on node. Because potato is a client side variable that will then when used in server retrieve the value of the amount to be paid in node.

Where/how do I put this so I can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How to do it is literally explained in the comments of that client-side code:

```
          return fetch("/api/orders", {
            method: "post",
            // use the "body" param to optionally pass additional order information
            // like product ids or amount
          })
```

Comment: Not sure how though. I've only used jquery, Which is $.post('/path', object)
How do I sent the object?

Comment: Using the 'body' parameter in the fetch